# HTACCESS redirect controller folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am stuck at a problem with .*HTACCESS* FILE.
I am using CodeIgniter 3

**Scenario:**

We have a domain `https://example.com` and the admin panel is in a folder like 
`application/controllers/manage/<controllers here>`

Now I need this to happen.

If someone goes to `https://example.com/manage` should be redirected to 
`https://admin.example.com/manage`.

Keep in mind that both subdomain & main domain points to same directory.

Also I want this to happen:

If someone goes to any url like 
`https://admin.example.com/<anyhting-other-than-manage>`
 to redirect to 
`https://example.com/<anything-other-than-manage>`
Here is my current `.htaccess`

```
# gtranslate config
RewriteRule ^(af|sq|am|ar|hy|az|eu|be|bn|bs|bg|ca|ceb|ny|zh-CN|zh-TW|co|hr|cs|da|nl|en|eo|et|tl|fi|fr|fy|gl|ka|de|el|gu|ht|ha|haw|iw|hi|hmn|hu|is|ig|id|ga|it|ja|jw|kn|kk|km|ko|ku|ky|lo|la|lv|lt|lb|mk|mg|ms|ml|mt|mi|mr|mn|my|ne|no|ps|fa|pl|pt|pa|ro|ru|sm|gd|sr|st|sn|sd|si|sk|sl|so|es|su|sw|sv|tg|ta|te|th|tr|uk|ur|uz|vi|cy|xh|yi|yo|zu)/(.*)$ /gtranslate/gtranslate.php?glang=$1&gurl=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(af|sq|am|ar|hy|az|eu|be|bn|bs|bg|ca|ceb|ny|zh-CN|zh-TW|co|hr|cs|da|nl|en|eo|et|tl|fi|fr|fy|gl|ka|de|el|gu|ht|ha|haw|iw|hi|hmn|hu|is|ig|id|ga|it|ja|jw|kn|kk|km|ko|ku|ky|lo|la|lv|lt|lb|mk|mg|ms|ml|mt|mi|mr|mn|my|ne|no|ps|fa|pl|pt|pa|ro|ru|sm|gd|sr|st|sn|sd|si|sk|sl|so|es|su|sw|sv|tg|ta|te|th|tr|uk|ur|uz|vi|cy|xh|yi|yo|zu)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^(assets|uploads)/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^(manage)/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(manage)/ https://admin.example.com/manage%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 


# procedure was miss spelled
Redirect 301 /yellwo /yellow

# Redirect 301 ......
```

Please help

UPDATE: Following does seems to work for redirecting  `admin.example.com<NOT-MANAGE-URI>` to `example.com/<NOT-MANAGE-URI>`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#gtranslate code 
# ........

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^(assets|uploads)/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# REDIRECT ADMIN

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/manage/
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

.......
```

After this:
URL in browser `https://admin.example.com/about-us` redirects to `https://example.com/about-us` which is correct.

but writing `https://admin.example.com/manage/` redirects to `https://example.com/index.php/manage/`

Comment: What is not working with your current set of rules?

Comment: `https://example.com/manage` does not redirect to `https://admin.example.com/manage`.

though `https://admin.example.com/manage` redirects to `https://example.com/manage`

Comment: Of course `/manage` won’t redirect, if your pattern is `^(manage)/`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule at top of your .htaccess to redirect `example.com/manage` to `admin.example.com/manage`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^manage(?:/.*)?$ https://admin.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^manage/ https://admin.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=302,NE,L]
`
did not redirect as expected.
`https://example.com/manage` does not redirect to `https://admin.example.com/manage`

Comment: `https://example.com/manage` does not redirect to `https://admin.example.com/manage`

Comment: Manage is a directory in `application/controllers` directory. So this is not something physically present at `example.com/manage`. its more like `example.com/index.php/manage/`

Comment: This works fine on my Apache so it is not working due to some local config issue on your end.